# How change in properties on report viewer

Tags: c#, reporting-services

How can I change location in properties Tablix1 on the report viewer  via expression?

How control any value on properties?

How can I change the characteristics of the report like its place by equation?

Comment: I don't think if there is a method other that changing rdl/rdlc raport with some Xml library (like System.Xml.dll)

Comment: Please add a tag to tell us what "report viewer" component you are using.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I restructured your question, added question marks and added a tag. Please review the tag (Try to add the specific version you use).  Please see [the editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information on formatting. Please try to put only one question to a post and try to add some example what you already have and be more specific what you are attempting to achieve. The current formulation of the question will probably lead to close as too broad.  Good luck!